# How to set library version with gradle plugin 3.2?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my android library project I used to do this:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavourName = variant.productFlavors.get(0).name
    def buildTypeName = variant.buildType.name

    def buildVersion = calculateVersion( flavourName, buildTypeName )
    variant.mergedFlavor.versionName = buildVersion
}
```

And this worked fine up until gradle plugin `3.1.3`. Now I am trying out `3.2.0-beta04` (as its much much faster when using vanilla cmake) and I am getting this error:

```
versionName cannot be set on a mergedFlavor directly.
versionNameOverride can instead be set for variant outputs using the following syntax:
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionNameOverride = "6.12.0"
        }
    }
}
```

OK, I apply the suggestion:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavourName = variant.productFlavors.get(0).name
    def buildTypeName = variant.buildType.name

    def buildVersion = calculateVersion( flavourName, buildTypeName )
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionNameOverride = buildVersion
    }
}
```

and now I get this error:

```
 Could not set unknown property 'versionNameOverride' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.LibraryVariantOutputImpl.
```

It appears that `versionNameOverride` property is implemented only for application variants, not for the library variants. Does that mean that support for setting Android AAR version is now deprecated? Or is there another way to achieve that?

EDIT: Note that setting `versionName` field in `defaultConfig` section works for my library project - it just does not work setting up programmatically with the method described above.

Comment: Did you report an issue in their issue tracker?

Comment: No, I didn't. I don't see that as a bug - I see it as the change in behaviour. In my case, I was able to make `calculateVersion` depend only on `flavourName`, so I call it when setting `versionName` for each flavour of my library.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bug; if you do report in issuetracker.google.com, you can get an answer from an authoritative source (e.g. Tor or Xavier); and in case it's an actual omission they can do something about it... (It's still in beta, so may have just missed it)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've reported the issue on Google's issue tracker. The issue is available [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112492574)

Answer (score -1):

Try to change  `variant.productFlavors.get(0).name` to `def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor`, than set name and version code for flavour like that

```
flavor.versionName = versionName
flavor.versionCode = versionCode
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.setVersionNameOverride(versionName)
        output.setVersionCodeOverride(versionCode)
    }
```